Access Distinct and Sum Query
In order to help me prepare for camping trips, I'm creating a DB where I can pick what recipes I want to make and print a list of ingredients I need to bring. I've got the following query and results:


The Access-generated SQL:
SELECT tblRecipeIngredients.IngredientID, tblIngredients.Cooler, tblIngredients.Ingredient, tblIngredients.UnitOfMeasure, tblRecipeIngredients.Quantity, tblRecipes.Planned
FROM tblIngredients INNER JOIN (tblRecipes INNER JOIN tblRecipeIngredients ON tblRecipes.RecipeID = tblRecipeIngredients.RecipeID) ON tblIngredients.IngredientID = tblRecipeIngredients.IngredientID
WHERE (((tblRecipes.Planned)=True))
ORDER BY tblIngredients.Cooler, tblIngredients.Ingredient;

So far, so good. However, since some ingredients are used in multiple recipes, there are multiple rows for them. For those, I would like to have one row with the total quantity for that ingredient. I have tried numerous combinations of DISTINCT, SUM, GROUP BY, etc. but no matter what I try I get an error saying that some column is not included as "part of an aggregate function".
Is there a way to make my query and/or VBA do what I want?

@Parfait: I've added the SQL. Access 2010 works just fine for me, whether MS supports it or not.

Please post attempted query which raises error not original one that works. Your need sounds like a straightforward aggregate query. Search for that type of SQL query or even search by your error. Always research before asking.

Enable Grouping in query design. Leave everything on "Group by" except Quantity, where you use Sum. Done.

You will aggregate using SUM(tblIngredients.Quantity) to get a sum of quantity for the ingredient, and then toss every other column in your SELECT clause into the GROUP BY clause:
SELECT tblRecipeIngredients.IngredientID, tblIngredients.Cooler, tblIngredients.Ingredient, tblIngredients.UnitOfMeasure, SUM(tblRecipeIngredients.Quantity) as Quantity, tblRecipes.Planned
FROM tblIngredients INNER JOIN (tblRecipes INNER JOIN tblRecipeIngredients ON tblRecipes.RecipeID = tblRecipeIngredients.RecipeID) ON tblIngredients.IngredientID = tblRecipeIngredients.IngredientID
WHERE (((tblRecipes.Planned)=True))
GROUP BY tblRecipeIngredients.IngredientID, tblIngredients.Cooler, tblIngredients.Ingredient, tblIngredients.UnitOfMeasure, tblRecipes.Planned
ORDER BY tblIngredients.Cooler, tblIngredients.Ingredient;


Thank you!! Between this and Andre's comment to my post, I finally have my solution after days of searching. It never occurred to me to group by everything.

That's the trick with a GROUP BY query. Every column in your SELECT either has to be wrapped into an aggregate function (sum(), max(), avg(), etc) OR it has to be listed in your GROUP BY clause. Otherwise it will just error out. That's the case on every RDBMS (except Mysql before version 5.7.2 which allowed that kind of nonsense).
